# Inputs shape is uknown during training (model subclassing)

Tags: tensorflow

Consider following model

```
class FractalNeuralNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, class_number):
        super(FractalNeuralNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.box_counting_patches = [BoxCountingPatch(box_size) for box_size in range(3, 41 + 1, 2)]
        
        self.chebyshev = ChebyshevBinaryPatch()
        self.euclidean = EuclideanBinaryPatch()
        self.manhattan = ManhattanBinaryPatch()
        
        self.percolation_c = PercolationC()
        self.percolation_m = PercolationM()
        self.percolation_q = PercolationQ()
        
        self.probability = ProbabilityMatrix()
        self.fractal_dimension = FractalDimension()
        self.lacunarity = Lacunarity()
        
        self.assemble = AssembleFractalImage()
        self.resize = tf.keras.layers.Resizing(width=224, height=224)
        self.rescale = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1./255)
        
        self.mobilenet_v2 = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4", 
                                           output_shape=[1280],
                                           trainable=False)
        self.combine = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.score = tf.keras.layers.Dense(class_number, activation='softmax')
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = tf.ensure_shape(inputs, self.ensure_input_shape)
        
        box_counting_patches = [box_counting_patch(inputs) for box_counting_patch in self.box_counting_patches]

        chebyshev = self.chebyshev(inputs=box_counting_patches)
        euclidean = self.euclidean(inputs=box_counting_patches)
        manhattan = self.manhattan(inputs=box_counting_patches)

        percolation_c = self.percolation_c(inputs=[chebyshev, euclidean, manhattan])
        percolation_m = self.percolation_m(inputs=[chebyshev, euclidean, manhattan])
        percolation_q = self.percolation_q(inputs=[chebyshev, euclidean, manhattan])

        probability = self.probability(inputs=[chebyshev, euclidean, manhattan])

        fractal_dimension = self.fractal_dimension(inputs=probability)
        lacunarity = self.lacunarity(inputs=probability)

        fractal_output = self.assemble(
            inputs=[
                fractal_dimension, 
                lacunarity, 
                percolation_c, 
                percolation_m, 
                percolation_q
            ]
        )
        fractal_output = self.resize(fractal_output)
        fractal_output = self.rescale(fractal_output)
        fractal_output = self.mobilenet_v2(fractal_output)

        original_output = self.rescale(inputs)
        original_output = self.mobilenet_v2(original_output)

        combined_output = self.combine([fractal_output, original_output])
        output = self.score(combined_output)

        return output
```

Every custom layer here is not trainable, they just perform calculations - extract fractal features from images.

The model is trained with the following code:

```py
model = FractalNeuralNetwork(
    class_number=CLASS_NUMBER
)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(
    training_set, 
    validation_data=validation_set, 
    epochs=1
)
```

The first batch comes with a normal shape (None, 224, 224, 3) but the second (None, None, None, None) and it break my model. Why does it happen?

Comment: Can you share the sample dataset or shape of your input data. Thanks!